# Looking for seating chart data

Tags: dictionary, vector, gis, mapbox

Is there a place I can find vector data for seating charts of popular US venues(say, Oracle Arena, Staples Center, etc)? Even one or two venues would do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about vectors... this site has a few non-vector charts. you could always draw new ones or contact the venue directly

http://www.vividseats.com/venues/

Comment: Thanks. I have seen vividseats, tickpick, etc. I was wondering if there is a data-only source they get their data from.

Comment: I would assume they got the data directly from the venues or through booking agents who have that information... have you seen seatgeek? they actually use leaflet and embed js that spits out the venues seating charts as json...